# Updating database table is failing using update clause in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

am trying to update a batch of columns in a table called customer . it works when i update two columns when hard coded the data.my aim is to fetch data from another table will updating the other. please here. it's not throwing any exception but just the code is not running . Thanks in advance

```
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            customerdata.stream().forEach((row) -> {
                session.beginTransaction();
// record data loggingg of customer import data transaction
            String sql = "UPDATE Customer SET first_name = :first_name ,second_name = :second_name,"
                    + "other_names = :other_name,gender = :gender,"
                    + "date_opened = :date_opened,date_approved = :date_approved,branch_code = :branch_code,"
                    + "national_id_number = :national_id_number,crb_number = :crb_number,"
                    + "passport_number = :passport_number,passport_expiry_date = :passport_expiry_date,"
                    + "voters_number = :voters_number,student_id_number = :student_id_number,"
                    + "employer_id_number = :employer_id_number,finance_card_number = :finance_card_number,"
                    + "driving_permit_number = :driving_permit_number,nssf_number = :nssf_number,tin_number = :tin_number,"
                    + "police_id_number = :police_id_number,updf_number = :updf_number,"
                    + "mobile = :mobile,telephone1 = :telephone1,telephone2 = :telephone2,"
                    + "email = :email ,is_salaried = :is_salaried,plot_number = :plot_number,postal_address = :postal_address,"
                    + "street = :street,account_operating_mode = :account_operating_mode,"
                    + "primary_account_type = :primary_account_type,"
                    + "address_type = :address_type,address_description = :address_description,dob_given = :dob_given,"
                    + "date_of_birth = :date_of_birth, client_type = :client_type, country_of_origin = :country_of_origin,"
                    + "city_of_origin = :city_of_origin,city_description = :city_description, employment_type = :employment_type,"
                    + "introducer_details_available = :introducer_details_available,literacy_level = :literacy_level,"
                    + "literacy_description = :literacy_description,marital_status = :marital_status,"
                    + "marital_status_description = :marital_status_description,"
                    + "nationality = :nationality,number_of_dependants = :number_of_dependants,residence = :residence,"
                    + "residence_type = :residence_type ,resident_state = :resident_state,type_of_id = :type_of_id,"
                    + "client_status = :client_status ,date_closed = :date_closed WHERE rim = :rim";

            Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
                query.setParameter("fname", row[2].toString());
                query.setParameter("second_name", row[3].toString());
                query.setParameter("other_name", row[4].toString());
                query.setParameter("gender", row[5].toString());
                query.setParameter("date_opened", (Date) row[6]);
                query.setParameter("date_approved", (Date) row[7]);
                query.setParameter("branch_code", row[8].toString());
                query.setParameter("national_id_number", Integer.parseInt(row[9].toString()));
                query.setParameter("crb_number", row[10].toString());
                query.setParameter("passport_number", row[11].toString());
                query.setParameter("passport_expiry_date", (Date) row[12]);
                query.setParameter("voters_number", row[13].toString());
                query.setParameter("student_id_number", row[14].toString());
                query.setParameter("employer_id_number", row[15].toString());
                query.setParameter("finance_card_number", row[16].toString());
                query.setParameter("driving_permit_number", row[17].toString());
                query.setParameter("nssf_number", row[18].toString());
                query.setParameter("tin_number", row[19].toString());
                query.setParameter("police_id_number", row[20].toString());
                query.setParameter("updf_number", row[21].toString());
                query.setParameter("mobile", row[22].toString());
                query.setParameter("telephone1", row[23].toString());
                query.setParameter("telephone2", row[24].toString());
                query.setParameter("email", row[25].toString());
                query.setParameter("is_salaried", (Boolean) row[26]);
                query.setParameter("plot_number", row[27].toString());
                query.setParameter("postal_address", Integer.parseInt(row[28].toString()));
                query.setParameter("street", row[29].toString());
                query.setParameter("account_operating_mode", Integer.parseInt(row[30].toString()));
                query.setParameter("primary_account_type", Integer.parseInt(row[31].toString()));
                query.setParameter("address_type", row[32].toString());
                query.setParameter("address_description", row[33].toString());
                query.setParameter("dob_given", (Boolean) row[34]);
                query.setParameter("date_of_birth", (Date) row[35]);
                query.setParameter("client_type", row[36].toString());
                query.setParameter("country_of_origin", row[37].toString());
                query.setParameter("city_of_origin", row[38].toString());
                query.setParameter("city_description", row[39].toString());
                query.setParameter("employment_type", row[40].toString());
                query.setParameter("introducer_details_available", row[41].toString());
                query.setParameter("literacy_level", row[42].toString());
                query.setParameter("literacy_description", row[43].toString());
                query.setParameter("marital_status", row[44].toString());
                query.setParameter("marital_status_description", row[45].toString());
                query.setParameter("nationality", row[46].toString());
                query.setParameter("number_of_dependants", Integer.parseInt(row[47].toString()));
                query.setParameter("residence", row[48].toString());
                query.setParameter("residence_type", row[49].toString());
                query.setParameter("resident_state", row[50].toString());
                query.setParameter("type_of_id", Integer.parseInt(row[51].toString()));
                query.setParameter("client_status", row[52].toString());
                query.setParameter("date_closed", (Date) row[53]);
                //setting rim data 
                query.setParameter("rim",row[1].toString());

                query.executeUpdate();
                session.getTransaction().commit();
                System.err.println(xx++ + "RIM LOOPED:" + row[1].toString());
            });
            try {
                session.close();
                System.out.println("Update customer ends. . . . . . . . . . .");

            } catch (NullPointerException nullPointer) {
                System.out.println("updateing data log data property ::<updateEntireContent()>: Customer session object is closed.Exception handled. . .>>" + nullPointer);
            }
```

Comment: Do you get any error message? If yes please post the stacktrace.

Comment: the code is not executing past Query query = session.createQuery(sql);  beacuse i tested it by printing out some text. and it's not throwing any error at all

Comment: i finally worked it out. some of the objects from a different database had NULL values so i had to first clean them first for the code to run.Thanks guys